# joystick continuous cmd_vel

Tags: navigation, joystick, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear friends,

I'm using hector_quadrotor simulation in ROS hydro with gazebo.
I can successfully use an xbox joystick to move as it is described in the tutorials.

In order to move it in x of y direction I should point the stick and repeated again and again the movement to send the related message.
Is it how it works or I have set something wrong?
Could this be done continuously, meaning that I can keep the stick pointing in the x direction and the messages transmitted continuously?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214753/joystick-continuous-cmd_vel/) by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2015-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case the joystick interfaced with ROS via [joy/joy_node](http://wiki.ros.org/joy), you can try `~autorepeat_rate` parameter as described [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/joy/html/):

> **Auto-Repeat/Signal Loss**
>
> The joy_node takes an
> "~autorepeat_rate" parameter. If the
> linux kernal receives no events during
> the autorepeat interval, it will
> automatically repeat the last value of
> the joystick. This is an important
> safety feature, and allows users to
> recover from a joystick that has timed
> out.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on 2015-07-29**:
Thanks Boris :)
And yes, as the name says it is not ON(1) or OFF(0) but actually a rate in Hz!

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-07-29**:
Glad it helped :)